# convert video file format matlab

Tags: video-capture, video-processing, matlab

I have many small video clips in different formats (.avi, .mpg, etc).
I want to convert all the files to .mp4 format using matlab.

The reason for the conversion is: I am extracting frames from videos and save them as images. but when I use .mpg, .avi formats I am unable to determine the number of frames in each video clip.

So I need to convert the files to .mp4 format. Could you please let me know are there any way to do it using matlab.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of **FFMpeg** to convert and then read the output using **MATLAB**.
for instance;

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.avi myfile.mp4
```

[Readme Link](http://dudiek.wordpress.com/2008/06/15/15)